# Custom Control binding issue (Windows universal 10)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, win-universal-app

i'm trying to bind a parameter of my custom control to a list. However it searches in the wrong ViewModel. It searches in te ViewModel of my control(ViewModelUserControlVM) and not the the ViewModel of the page where my control is located.

user control xaml

```
 <UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:ViewModelUserControlVM/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<ListView Name="lst">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

User control code behind

```
    public object ItemsSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (object)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
        (
        "ItemsSource",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(FlipListview),
        new PropertyMetadata(
            new object(),
            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourceChanged)
        )
    );
```

Mainpage xaml

```
    <local:CustomControl ItemsSource="{Binding list, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

edit

mainpage.xaml

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MainPageVM/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

MainPageVM

```
    public class MainPageVM : ViewModelBase
    {
    public List<Model> list { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand SelectedItemCommand { get; set; }

    public Model SelectedItem { get; set; }

    public MainPageVM()
    {
        SelectedItem = new Model();
        SelectedItemCommand = new RelayCommand(SelectedItem);

        list = new List<Model>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new Model("url" + i, "title" + i, "desc" + i));
        }
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => list);
    }
   }
```

User control code behind

```
        public CustomControl()
        {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        }
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the DataContext of your UserControl is ViewModelUserControlVM, any Bindings in it will look to that DataContext.  If you need a parent control to bind to the dependency property to pass something from its (the parent control) DataContext, you can set the DataContext of the UserControls main panel (Grid, StackPanel, etc.) to your ViewModelUserControlVM.  This will cause the control itself to look "upwards" in the visual tree to find a DataContext.  In this case, your MainPage's viewmodel.

It appears by the partial code you have shared that you are attempting to Bind the ItemsSource dependency property to something in the MainPage, but then overriding the UserControl's DataContext by assigning the entire UserControl's DataContext to a different viewmodel.

More complete code would support or contest this theory.

**update below**

Thank you for the additional code.  It is still unclear what the ultimate goal is - for example, the selected item is mentioned, but not used and we don't know the relevance of the user control's viewmodel.  So, I threw together a little something that simply shows a list in the main viewmodel and binds to a usercontrol that is looking for a list of that type.  I hope it helps get you where you are trying to go...
(note: I used the MVVMLight library)

MainPageVM:

```
public class MainPageVM : ViewModelBase
    {
        private List<Model> _list = new List<Model>();
        public List<Model> list
        {
            get { return _list; }
            set { Set(ref _list, value); }
        }



        public MainPageVM()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                list.Add(new Model("url" + i, "title" + i, "desc" + i));
            }
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => list);
        }
    }
```

MainPage xaml (DataContext is the MainVM):

```
<Page
    x:Class="App8.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App8"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:MainPageVM />
    </Page.DataContext>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <local:CustomControl ItemsSource="{Binding list, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

CustomControl code behind (note the datacontext setting in the ctor - DataContext of control is whatever is using it, but the controls inside the LayoutRoot grid will use the control's dependency properties):

```
public CustomControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
        }



        public List<Model> ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (List<Model>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ItemsSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(List<Model>), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourceChanged)));

        private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

CustomControl xaml:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App8.CustomControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App8"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ListView Name="lst" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="Url">
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In a nutshell, the ListView's itemsource is bound to whatever CustomControl's ItemsSource dependency property is.  CustomControl's ItemsSource's DataContext is whatever DataContext is using the control.  I hope it helps you out.

Comment: it's close, but now my binding in my CustomControl doesn't work. it is a binding in te a control in a style i apply to Listview.

Comment: i'm trying to do a work around. in loaded event i'm doing this.
            Style templatedControl = ((CustomControl)sender).lst.Style;
            SetterBaseCollection set = templatedControl.Setters;
            List<object> list = set.ToList<object>();
            Setter setter = (Setter)list[13];

however i can't get the controls in that setter. which is a control template.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would work like this :

```
 <local:CustomControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.list, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

You can find additional information about x:Bind [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension)

Comment: i don't like using x:bind because it doesn't use a ViewModel.